# Tinymce not displaying images

Tags: php

I use tinymce. The upload image button is working fine and images are uploaded to the server but I am unable to view them in the editor. Also, it is neither showing the preview nor thumbnail.

Please help me, I don't know what I am doing wrong.

I have added an image for reference: [tinymce screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RScqe.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Someone will fix this post for you soon.. I pressed the wrong button.

Comment: Looks like a problem with paths... have you checked your configuration for absolute/relative paths? Check the resulting path as well (check dev tools). It should give you a hint.